# Having problems with Mail and a few other programs freezing

Tags: email, crash, install

I have a brand new macbook. I don't  really know a ton about macs...I'm newly switched from a life of windows pc's.  I keep reading about how you can unintall and then reinstall your OS. I can't get my head around how you would do this, bc w/windows you would have no way to get on the internet to access the program without an OS on the computer. I can imagine getting a drive to put it on, from which you could reinstall, but that seems to defeat the point if you think your version could be corrupt and want to ditch it and get a clean copy.

My computer is the Macbook(not an air or pro), so it has no drives and only one port. I do not have any external drives.

When I bought this machine I asked the genius bar to transfer my files, music and photos only. They  ended up transferring my entire drive, which included windows folders.I've deleted most of this, but am not sure if I've removed everything and do not know if this could be the source of the problem. Could these files have corrupted anything?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. Sorry if I appear ignorant! It's only bc I am when it comes to this :~)

Comment: On a brand new MacBook, usually there is no need to reinstall the operating system, that is only done if system is stuck and will not boot.

Comment: We do not know what you deleted, but most probaly you did not damage the OSX. So tell us which programs a freezing so we can clear that.

Comment: hi. thanks. SO, mail and safari are what are freezing. Not sure what to do. I assumed that these where part of the OS

Comment: what I mean by freezing @Buscar웃, I am getting either a blue or multi-colored spinning wheel on Safari.

Comment: I do not know what you deleted. There is always the "Safe mode" to test. Hold Shit key during boot. Now try Safari. Reinstalling OS X will restore Safari and Mail, but not sure it will fix your problems (of possibly 3d party app interfering). So go ahead and reinstall OS X and let us know if that solved it.

Comment: I'm going to try tonight. Really appreciate your help. Line so long to get help at store!

Comment: I had to reinstall the OS X because of other problem with Music anyway. It has been two days and no problems with Mail or Safari so I think this solved the issues I was having all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, congratulations on upgrading to a Mac, I'm a Windows "switcher", too, and will never go back. Secondly, as far as reinstalling a fresh copy of OS X (pronounced *oh-es-ten* NOT *oh-es-ex*) you will want to turn your MacBook off, then turn it back on, but while holding the Option key. Release it when you see two icons of hard drives, whatever you named your startup disk ("Macintosh HD" by default) and one labeled Recovery. Select Recovery by highlighting it with the arrow keys, and then hitting the enter key. Once there, you should see the option to "Reinstall OS X" select it and just follow the on-screen instructions from there. Make sure to select your start up disk, again named "Macintosh HD" by default, where it asks which drive to reinstall it on.

Comment: thank you. If I do this, will my files be secure. I didn't get a backup drive bc I thought that i would back up to iCloud, which i learned is not possible,

Comment: Everything should stay the same, you're just reinstalling the OS. All your files will still be there.

Comment: Thanks. So, another user just indicated this may not be the right thing for a fix, as it (reinstalling OS X is only necessary if machine won't boot. I'm not having that problem. So now, I'm waiting and researching b/f doing that.

Comment: Reinstallation might solve the issue, Mail is a system application.

Comment: That was my understanding, but  I am literally without a clue. I appreciate your answering.

Comment: Do you guys think it would be worth trying the beta release El Capitan instead of reinstalling? Or, do the beta programs have to many bugs still being worked out, such that it would/could raise more issues to deal with.

Comment: Definitely not! Beta software would only raise more issues.

Comment: Not having a backup is asking for trouble. I wouldn't reinstall without a Time Machine backup, more so if you are a novice user.

Comment: Thank you both.  I sort of figured but thought i'd ask. Re Time Machine, any recommendations for a good drive that is not too crazy expensive?

Comment: If you want a hard drive that lasts get a WD MyPassport for Mac. It's a great drive, plus I got mine with 1 TB storage for like $100.